# Extjs Combo - Set store load in render function or by click a button

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

```
        xtype: 'combo',
        id: 'example',
        triggerAction:  'all',
        forceSelection: true,
        editable:       false,
        allowBlank: false,
        fieldLabel:     'example',
        mode: 'remote',
        displayField:'name',
        valueField: 'id',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        fields: [
                            {name: 'id'},
                            {name: 'name'}
                        ],
                        //autoLoad: false,
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: 'example.php',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'rows'
                            }
                        }
            }
        })
        ,listeners: {
            render: function(combo) {
                combo.store().load(); // not working
            }
        }
```

If i using `autoload: true` That work well. But I want to control my load and I using `combo.store().load();` or `Ext.getCmp('example').store.load();` in render function or by click a button. But everything not working.

How can i do that thanks

Comment: use Ext.getCmp('example').getStore().load();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(component ref).getStore().load();`

like:

```
Ext.getCmp('example').getStore().load(); 
combo.getStore().load();
```

Comment: Sorry i just missing Ext.getCmp('example').value = '0'; to see change value :(. Thank u :)